# Multiple Grails apps accessing the same database

Tags: grails

I am considering breaking my Grails app into two separate apps: admin and customer facing. The admin app would also do a lot of backend heavy lifting.

Has anyone done this? Lessons learned? I'm particularly wondering about the best way to handle domain objects as well as potential issues with concurrency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run into race/locking conditions but I've seen this done on many occasions. My only suggestion is that you not maintain separate domain classes. Put common domain classes in a plugin and install said plugin in both applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do that, the best way is to separate existing Domain classes too, instead of enable multiple direct access from all the apps. Keep each Domain class persisted by the app mostly closed to it. For other apps, they should access the data through RESTful service provided by the data-hosting app.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to keep the domain classes exactly the same, therefore generating same db tables.

I don't think concurrency will be much of a problem, as modern dbms usually handle that really well.

Comment: DB-level concurrency isn't a problem, it's the second-level cache that you have to watch out for.  All the apps need to share the same cache to keep things consistent.

Comment: Caching aside, I don't see how this is any different than a clustered Grails environment.